# Why does this code with TCHAR and variadic arguments behave this way?

Tags: c++, variadic

I have the following helper function:

```
inline void DebugMessage(const TCHAR* fmtstr, ...)
{
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, fmtstr);

        TCHAR buffer[256];
        StringCbVPrintf(buffer, 256, fmtstr, args);
        OutputDebugString(buffer);

        va_end(args);
}
```

And I call it twice like so:

```
DebugMessage(_T("Test %d\n", 1)); // incorrectly closed _T()
DebugMessage(_T("Test %d\n"), 1); // correctly closed _T()
```

I get the following output:

```
Test 0
Test 1
```

The 2nd case works as expected. I am confused why the first case functions at all, rather than being an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_T` is not a function, it's a macro that (in a Unicode build) expands to `L ## x`. The misplaced bracket doesn't cause a compile error, it simply changes which parts of the line gets consumed by the macro.

The macro only takes one parameter (`x`) and so in the first case, with the incorrect closure, the second parameter (`1`) is simply discarded, and the number you get in your output is simply a result of random data on the stack.

Note that by default, VS 2012 will issue a C4002 warning about this (*too many actual parameters for macro*) so you may want to check that you have warnings enabled properly.

Comment: +1 Your preprocessor should issue a stern warning if incorrect parameter counts are supplied to a non-varadic macro (at least mine does) and outright error if warnings are configured to do so.

Comment: Yeah I just added a note about that.

Comment: Anyway to do this in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: Be kind to your preprocessor, for she can be a heartless wench if you mistreat her =)

Comment: The warning existed at least in VS 2008: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y37zb304(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: It's warning 4002. To treat it as an error, go to "Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Treat Specific Warnings As Errors"